# How to retrieve single record in WCF RIA Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using WCF RIA Services and I have a domain service method that returns a single entity. In my Silverlight client project I'm now using following code to retrieve that entity:

```
ctxt.Load(ctxt.GetEmployeeByNumberQuery("ABC123")).Completed += new System.EventHandler(EmployeeLoad_Completed);


    void EmployeeLoad_Completed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee myEmployee = (sender as LoadOperation<Employee>).Entities.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Is there any better or more elegant method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. That's the minimum amount you'd have to write to get a single entity.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I couldn't find much documentation on single entities in RIA and was wondering about this.